# python list elements NO Splitting

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django, list

I have the problem, that python split up a list with only one integer element into more parts.

For example:

`['17','23']` -> is working perfect with two elements 17,23

But

`['17']` -> is splitting up into `['1','7']` Why?

I get the date from javascript where i read the checkboxes, then with axios i send the data to the server (django)

code:

```
      var ids = []
      var dataForm = document.forms.ids // get the form

      for (var i=0;i<dataForm.length;i++){
        if (dataForm[i].checked) {
        ids.push(dataForm[i].getAttribute('data-sid'))
       }
      }
            axios.post("{% url 'apps:doSomething' %}", {
                params: {
                    ids:ids,
                    }
                })
```

then it is getting to django views doSomething. Request.POST is for example `<QueryDict: {'ids[]': ['16', '17']}>` the length = 2 and everything is perfect

But if the Request.POST is for example `<QueryDict: {'ids[]': ['17']}>` because only one element has been choosen on the homepage python tells me that the length = also 2 and it splits up the 17 into two parts ? ['1','7'] and i don't know why, because i don't send a string i send an array to django/python

code views.py

```
def doSomething(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    sids = request.POST['sids[]']
    print("sids %s" %sids) # for example: sids ['16', '17'] or sids 16 if only one element
    print("Length sids %s" %len(sids)) # Both times 2
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: How do you split a list?

Comment: Share the code please.

Comment: Share the appropriate code

Answer (score 0):

Such a thing is by no means possible. You must use a string, using comma, followed by a space, as a separator :

```py
raw_number = "17, 23"
number = raw_number.split(", ")
print(number)

['17', '23']
```

or

```py
raw_number = "1, 7, 2, 3"
number = raw_number.split(", ")
print(number)

['1', '7', '2', '3']
```